# My dictionary code: My template function doesn't run when i call it from another function

Tags: c++

Down here is my code for my dictionary,i have file node.cpp and singlelist.cpp created by my teacher, please notice at my **add()** function in **hashtable.cpp**,it can't execute **getelem()** function in **node.cpp**,if i creat a new work and **include"node.cpp"**,with my **word** data type and **char** type as a k key, it run normaly though, please show me where it's wrong (oh, my bad english, sory)

````
#ifndef NODE_CPP
#define NODE_CPP 1
#include"iostream"  
using namespace std;
template <class k,class t>
class node{
    private:
        k key;
        t elem;
        node* next;
    public:
        node();
        node* getnext(); //tra lai dia chi cua doi tuong do
        void setnext(node<k,t>* p);
        t getelem(); //tra lai dia chi cua phantu luu trong node;
        k getkey();
        void setelem(t e); //dat thay the phan tu luu tru trong node
        void setkey(k key);
};
template<class k,class t>
node<k,t>::node(){
    next=NULL;
}
template <class k,class t>
node<k,t> *node<k,t>::getnext(){
    return next;
}

template <class k,class t>
void node<k,t>::setnext(node<k,t> *p){
    next=p;
}

template<class k,class t>
t node<k,t>::getelem(){
    return elem;
}

template<class k,class t>
k node<k,t>::getkey(){
    return key;
}
template <class k,class t>
void node<k,t>::setelem(t e){
    this->elem=e;
}
template <class k,class t>
void node<k,t>::setkey(k key){
    this->key=key;
}
#endif
#include"iostream"
#include"slist.cpp"
using namespace std;

template<class k,class t>
class hash{
    private:
        singlelist<k,t>* a;
        int N;
    public:
        hash(){
            N=26;
            a=new singlelist<k,t>[N];
        }
        ~hash(){
            for(int i=0;i<26;i++){
                node<k,t> *pre=a[i].first();
                 while(pre!=NULL){
                    node<k,t> *temp=pre;
                    pre=pre->getnext();
                    delete temp;
        }
            delete a;
        }
        int hashfunc(k key){
            cout<<"hashfunc";
            return key%26;
        }
        void add(k key,t val);
        void remove(k key);
        singlelist<k,t> getlist(int i){
            return a[i];
        }
        node<k,t>* find(k key);
        bool contains(k key);
        int count(int i){return a[i].size();};
};
template<class k,class t>
void hash<k,t>::add(k key,t e){
    node<k,t> *p;
    cout<<"them tu";
    p->setelem(e);
    cout<<"setrlem";
    p->setkey(key);
    cout<<"setup";
    int index=hashfunc(key);
    cout<<index;
    a[index].insertlast(p->getelem());
    cout<<"ok";
}
template<class k,class t>
void hash<k,t>::remove(k key){
    int index=hashfunc(key);
    a[index]->first()=NULL;
    a[index]->last()=NULL;
}
template<class k,class t>
node<k,t>* hash<k,t>::find(k key){
    int index=hashfunc(key);
    if(index<=26&&index>=1)
        return a[index].first();
    return NULL;
}
template <class k,class t>
bool hash<k,t>::contains(k key)
{
    for(int i=0;i<26;i++)
        if(key==a[i].first()->getkey())
            return true;
    return false;
}
        this is my dictionary

#include"iostream"
#include"hash.cpp"
#include"string"
#include"fstream"
#include"slitr.cpp"
using namespace std;
struct word{
    string ta;
    string tv;
    void nhap(){
        cin.ignore();
        cout<<"nghia tieng anh:";getline(cin,ta);
        cout<<"nghia tieng viet:";getline(cin,tv);
        }
};
class dic{
    hash<char,word> *a;
    public:
        dic(){ a=new hash<char,word>;
        }
        void load();
        node<char,word>* findword(string x);
        void replace(string x);
        void add();
        void del(string x);
        void save();
};
// tim 1 tu trong tu dien
node<char,word>* dic::findword(string x){
    node<char,word> *p;
    int key=a->hashfunc(x[0]);
    p=a->find(key);
    if(p!=NULL)
    {   
        while(p->getnext()!=NULL)
        {
            if(p->getelem().ta==x)
                break;
            p=p->getnext();
        }
        if(p->getelem().ta==x)
            {
                return p;
            }
    }       
    return p;
}
// sua mot tu trong tu dien
void dic::replace(string x){
    node<char,word> *p;
    p=this->findword(x);
    if(p!=NULL){
        word q;
        q.nhap();
        p->setelem(q);
    }
    else cout<<"khong co tu can tim";
}
//them 1 tu moi vao tu diem;
void dic::add(){
    word q;
    q.nhap();
    a->add(q.ta[0],q);
}
void dic::del(string x){
    node<char,word>* p=this->findword(x);
    int i=a->hashfunc(x[0]);
    if(p!=NULL&&i<26&&i>=0){
        (this->a->getlist(i)).remove(p);
    }
}
void dic::load(){
    ifstream tudien;
    tudien.open("load.txt");
    cout<<"tao tu dien\n";
    word p;
    while(!tudien.eof())
    {
        tudien>>p.ta>>p.tv;
        cout<<"nhap xong";
        cout<<p.ta<<p.tv<<"1";
        this->a->add(p.ta[0],p);
        cout<<p.ta<<p.tv;
    }
    tudien.close();
    cout<<"dong tu dien";
}
void dic::save(){
    ofstream save;
    cout<<"mo file\n";
    save.open("savefile.txt");
    for(int i=0;i<26;i++)
    {
        if(this->a->count(i)!=0)
        {   
            node<char,word>* p=this->a->getlist(i).first();
            while(p->getnext()!=NULL){
                save<<p->getelem().ta<<"\n"<<p->getelem().tv<<endl;
                p=p->getnext();
            }
                save<<p->getelem().ta<<"\n"<<p->getelem().tv;
        }
    }
    save.close();
    cout<<"luu file";
}```
````

Comment: Please clarify exactly what you mean by: (1) "can't execute getelem() function"; (2) "create a new work"; (3) "run normally".  It's best if you try not to describe code or behavior in your own words.  Show the actual code, and the actual behavior.  If there are compiler errors, show them.  If there's wrong output, show the input and output.  Finally, it's unusual to #include actual CPP source files.  The convention is to expose an interface in a header, then compile sources individually and link them.  For templates however, the implementation is always done in the header file.

Comment: please correct the things that are mentioned in first comment , and there are more `#include"iostream"  ` why are you using quotes around it, it is a  standard header file , so you should use `#include <iostream>` and many places you did `#include "filename.cpp"` don't do that, only header files has to be used that way sources has to be linked.